# apach/spark-py docker image ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run my pyspark test suite in docker via [apache/spark-py](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/spark-py).

But when I try to install dependencies via interactive shell I get the following error:

```bash
% docker run -it apache/spark-py:v3.3.1 sh
...
sh-5.1$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
...
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.local'
Check the permissions.
```

I tried appending `--user` and got the same result. I tried using `sudo` but the image doesn't have it installed. I could create my own custom image, but I'm trying to just use the official image "as is" to avoid having to build and publish it so I can run it in Gitlab CI. I could do this, but it doesn't make sense why I can't just use the released image to install dependencies to run the spark commands I've built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so first I noticed that the [image layers](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/spark-py/v3.3.1/images/sha256-0d4fd8bcb2ad63a35c9ba5be278a3a34c28fc15e898307e458d501a7e11d6d51?context=explore) for the tag ends with:

```
USER 185
```

While other commands in `Dockerfile` run after `USER 0`.

So I ran:

```
$ cat /etc/passw

root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
...
185:x:185:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false
```

Looking at the docs for the `docker run` command you can specify the user to run a specific command under with the `--user` argument. So when I launch the contain using:

```
$ docker run -it --user 0 apache/spark-py:v3.3.1 sh
...
# whoami
root
```

And now `python3 -m pip install ...` works. Now I just need to figure out how to specify `--user` in Gitlab.